# How to combine list items without paragraph number with the previous ones that do have it? (python)

Tags: python, list, nlp

Is there a simple way to combine list elements of strings without paragraph numbers with the ones that do have it above them?

I have a long list like that:

```
['2. Text',
     'Text1',
     'Text2',
 '2.1. Text3',
      'Text4']
```

and I would like to get something like that:

```
['2. Text Text1 Text2',
 '2.1. Text3 Text4']
```

Comment: create two lists, iterate over your original list, when you hit an item that starts with a number, `' '.join()` the first list and append that element to the second list and clear the first list, otherwise append the element to the first list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not be the best method, but maybe this helps you.

```
lst = ['2. Text','Text1',
 'Text2','2.1. Text3','Text4']

new_lst = []
nested_lst = []

for el in lst:
  if el[0].isdigit() and nested_lst != []:
    new_lst.append(nested_lst)
    nested_lst = []

  nested_lst.append(el)

new_lst.append(nested_lst)
```